# image post request returns curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: docker, flask, curl

I'm using curl with
`curl -v -X POST -F image=@test1.png "http://localhost:8080/predict"`

it returns this error

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /predict HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 99941
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------a28faad032811913
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I've build a docker file and trying to run a machine learning model prediction in backend.

This is my Docker file

```
FROM python:
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python","app.py"]~
```

Docker commands used

```
docker build -t final:latest .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 final
```

Below is my app.py file. In which I'm applying classification model on image passed through predict route. This predict code was working in py file without flask application. But with docker and flask I'm stuck somewhere.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
import sys
import torch
from build_model import classificationModel
from image_preprocessing import preprocessing_img
import numpy as np
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
model = None

def predict(y_pred):
    ...
    res = label_dencoding[sort_label[0][0]]
    return res
      
def load_model():
    global model
    model = classificationModel()


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    prediction = {"success": False}
    load_model()
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        if flask.request.files["image"]:
            img = flask.request.files["image"]
            image = preprocessing_img(img)
            output = model(image)
            res = predict(output)
            prediction["predictions"] = []
            prediction["predictions"].append(res)
            prediction["success"] = True
    return flask.jsonify(prediction)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

Please forgive me if it's small mistake because I'm newbie to docker and flask.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Include your Dockerfile, and how you are starting your container. Empty reply from server could be caused by a number of things including an issue with the application in the container.

Comment: Hey, @programmerq thank you so muchh for noticing!!! I've added docker file and I'm not able to figure out where it went wrong!

Comment: you are now showing the Dockerfile, but not app.py nor the `docker run` command used to start the container. That info will be critical for a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for this! @programmerq I've added both the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> curl -v -d "image=@test1.png" -X POST "http://localhost:53607/predict"

that'll give you verbose for where exactly you are stuck